# protect function to be not overridden in ZSH

Tags: zsh

I have a file where my ZSH functions are defined, and I source it from my zshrc.
There are the set of helper functions which used only in other functions from that file.
My question is how can I keep readable names for those helpers (such as 'ask', etc.) and be sure that they will not be overridden later in other sourced files.
So, for example I have two functions:

```
helper() {
    # do something
}

function-i-want-to-use-in-shell() {
     helper # call helper, I want to be sure that it is 'my' helper
     # do something more
}
```

I want to protect `helper` for functions declared within that file.
It would be nice if I could wrap those functions in, for example, subshell `()` and then export function-i-want-to-use-in-shell to parent (I know this is impossible);
So I am looking for a convenient way to create something like their own scope for those functions, and make some of them global and some local.

[**EDIT**] 
I think another example will give better explanation of the behaviour I want to achieve:
So, for second example I have two files: `file1.sh` and `file2.sh`.
`file1.sh` the same as example above, in `file2.sh` another function `helper` defined. I want you to understand that `helper` from `file1.sh` it's just function for local usage (within that file), just snippet of code. Later in shell I want only use `function-i-want-to-use-in-shell` from `file1.sh` and `helper` from `file2.sh`. I do not want `helper` readonly, I just want it for local usage only. Maybe I can do something like "*namespace*" for functions in `file1.sh`, or somehow achieve javascript-like scoping lookup behaviour in that file. The only way I see to do it now is to refuse the condition to keep good, readable, self-explaining names of my helper functions, and 
give them names that are hardly to be invented by someone else, or use prefix for those functions. Oh, I just wanted to write something like `if ask "question"; then` but not `if my-local-ask "question"; then` in other my functions, and be sure that if someone (or I myself) will define later another function `ask` nothing will be broken

Comment: I'm surprised `typeset -rf helper` doesn't all you to make a function read-only; it seems like a very zsh-like thing to do.

Comment: @chepner I do not want make my function read-only I want to make it local-only

Answer (score 0):

It's a little heavy-handed, but you can use an autoloaded function to, if not prevent overriding a function, "reset" it easily before calling. For example.

```
# Assumes that $func_dir is a directory in your fpath;
% echo 'print bar' > $func_dir/helper
% helper () { print 9; }
% helper
9
% unset -f helper
% autoload helper
% helper
bar
```